# Can we do some local database (Rhom) operation using javascript in Rhodes

Tags: rhomobile, rhodes

I usually manipulate the Rhom records in the controller using the `create`, `new`, `update_attributes` methods.

But i wonder is there any way we can achieve these features through javascript, as we do in other framework like phonegap ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess no. Previously, Rhomobile had the support for Javascript. But i guess, on the current version they had withdrawn the support.

Comment: Ohh, its bad to hear that :(

Comment: Next version of the RhoMobile Suite include the possibility to write a complete application in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a complete application just using JavaScript in the next release of the RhoMobile Suite (v4.0).

If you take a look at the [new documentation](http://edgedocs.rhomobile.com/api/Orm#e0), and you try the [latest public beta](https://developer.motorolasolutions.com/docs/DOC-1817), you will see that the ORM API are now available from JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks, will surely look into this.